# localhost url in browser gives 404 error in xampp

Tags: xampp, http-error

I've installed XAMPP server and started Apache on port 8080. it worked fine but when I write in browser localhost it doesn't work. message displayed is " ***HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.***"

Comment: try: `localhost:8080` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Check your firewall settings. Which OS are you using?

Comment: if it is still giving error on http://localhost:8080 or http://127.0.0.1:8080, check your host file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in WINDOWS OR /etc/hosts file in LINUX. there should be "127.0.0.1       localhost" line. add if missing

Answer (score 0):

try localhost:8080. Also try, 127.0.0.1/8080 if the first method fails.